# Class interface duplication

Tags: c++, testing, design-patterns

I sometimes come across, mostly when working with old code, the situation that one class acts as a mere forwarding of the calls to another class. Imagine there is a old controller which controls somethings however some of those can be dedicated to a new class. Now, the old controller will call the new class interface.

Ex.

```
class Controller {
  public:
    void addObject(const std::string & id,
      const Object * obj) {
      m_Wrk.addObject(id, obj);
    }
  private:
    Worker m_Wrk;
};

class Worker {
  public:
    void addObject(const std::string & id,
      const Object * obj) {
      //do actual adding
    }
};
```

Now, when thinking about testing the software, the interfaces might need to be tested in both classes, and it is harder in the controller as it does not mostly as it is necessary to check worker changes on controller tests.

Is this usage particularly bad or is it okay to use this kind of design in an already existing code as explained above.

Thanks

Comment: Am I right that `m_Wrk` should be a pointer?

Comment: typo. it doesn't need to necessarily.

Comment: Isn't this essentially a PIMPL.  I guess I am struggling to understand the question.  Can you re-phrase this:

Now, when thinking about testing the software, the interfaces might need to be tested in both classes, and it is harder in the controller as it does not mostly as it is necessary to check worker changes on controller tests.

Is this usage particularly bad or is it okay to use this kind of design in an already existing code as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer whether this code is good or bad - it depends on circumstances. The code in question (except for the fact that `m_Wrk` field should be a pointer) is a [PImpl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) pattern, which is a kind of a [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) pattern. This pattern is used to split the abstraction and implementation so that they can change independently.

For example, if you write a C++ library and you'd like to provide a stable ABI which does not change if there're no changes in public interface, you could put the `Controller` interface in header, together with forward-declaration of `Worker` class, and put both interface and implementation of `Worker` in `.cpp` file. When `Worker` changes, the `Controller` ABI remains the same. If the implementation details were placed directly in `Controller` class, the ABI might change.

Also, such pattern (Bridge in general) allows you to use different implementations of the abstraction given, so, it's possible to separate inheritance in terms of interface extension and inheritance in terms of Liskov substitution.

Also, if the `Controller` implements the same interface as `Worker`, in future it can implement some additional behavior, like in the [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) pattern.

If one of these situations takes place in your project (or may take place in future), it's probably a good code. If no, it's just an unnecessary complication.